# Mobile Business Apps - any way to use XAML?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7

I'm making a business mobile app to run on Intermec rugged devices. I would like to use XAML/Silverlight/WPF. It seems that this is not possible and I will need to use WinForms. Can any gurus confirm this please?

Thanks a lot.

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point only Windows phone series 7 has Silverlight support which is due release end of this year. Currently Windows mobile 6.0/6.5 devices are largely available in the market that support WinForms. To develop windows phone series 7 app, you must use visual studio 2010 and surprisingly it does not support windows mobile 6.0/6.5 development. To develop for windows mobile 6.0/6.5 you must use visual studio 2008.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like I'm stuck using Winforms :(